# Are Pakistani nationals restricted to entering India through four airports only?

Tags: visas, air-travel, customs-and-immigration, india, pakistani-citizens

A Pakistani friend who needs to go to India was informed (very late, near visa approval) by an Indian embassy official (in Singapore) that he can only **enter* India** through one of the four major airports: Delhi, Mumbai, Kolkata and Chennai.

> * By *"enter"* I mean that the immigration officers (perhaps the equivalent of "customs agents" in the US) will allow the person to enter the country through the immigration checkpoint of an airport, or be detained at the checkpoint and barred from entering the country. This is **not** related to "customs" which deals with importing goods, or to being inside a flight that lands at the airport.

Direct flights to and from a smaller airport were already booked, which are now being changed to two-stop flight plan landing at one of the four ports internationally then transiting to a domestic flight to the original destination.

We searched online for any information about such restriction but could not find any. **Is this restriction as per Indian law?** Where can a reference to this restriction be found?

Comment: @hippietrail `customs-and-immigration` *(**border control** procedures; **referred to as 'immigration'** in most countries other than US)* appears to be a better tag than `regulations` *(Rules, regulations, and policies of organizations **as opposed to laws** of nations or governments.)*.

Comment: Your question doesn't ask anything about visas or about customs and immigration but does ask if India has rules about which airports Pakistanis can arrive at. You're not asking whether customs agents will accept you but whether India regulates which airports you can use.

Comment: That makes no sense. I mentioned "enter India", and by that I do mean whether the immigration officers *(as noted, it's not called 'customs agents' outside US)* will allow you to enter India via other airports, which is an immigration entry issue. This is indirectly related to visas as they can only be granted upon showing that you plan to enter India via one of these four ports, while it is directly related to immigration as mentioned. Do note that immigration means "entering the country" and **not** "permanently relocating to the country".

Comment: I have edited the question for clarity. I apologize if it wasn't clear earlier. Also please note that I did specifically ask about Indian law, while the `regulations` tag excerpt specifically **excludes** laws of nations of governments.

Comment: It was I who made the "customs and immigration" tag for the very reason that the two concepts are blurred and confused even by native English speakers especially given that they are or were previously often the same desk or the entire phrase is used on signage. Anyway in most countries the customs and immigration officers follow the rules set out by the government.

Comment: Now the "legal" and "rules" tags do blur a bit out of necessity. Many people will think of "legal" as "Would this mean I'm breaking the law, doing something criminal, and risking arrest?" whereas "rules" is broader and covers cases when you don't know or care whose jurisdiction the rules are, when you wouldn't expect to gain a criminal record by breaking them, etc. But it doesn't always matter which you use.

Comment: I would suggest "customs" and "immigration" should ideally be separate tags. In Asia we all collectively understand "immigration" to mean getting a stamp on your visa/passport and entering the country, whereas "customs" means importing goods (whether they are dutiable or non-dutiable goods). This is our common understanding, and at airports here, we first pass through immigration checkpoint getting approval to enter country, then (after entry and collecting baggage) declare any dutiable goods at the customs. I don't know how people in USA understand "customs and immigration". Sorry.

Comment: Unfortunately to most of us not in Asia "immigration" means the act of moving permanently to another country. Something that is off-topic on this site yet which gets asked frequently. You can find the naming of this tag discussed on the meta site a couple of years ago... Then again I can't find it so we must've discussed it in the chat room...

Comment: We call that "migration" or sometimes, "relocation/relocating". :) Perhaps: `migration` tag could be synonymous with *immigration* (with a note that it means the act of moving permanently, and one must not use it for checkpoint issues). And there could be an `immigration-checkpoint` or `immigration-entry` tag specifically for the act of getting approved at a port's checkpoint to enter a country through the port (air/land/sea). And then a `customs` tag for issues about customs (importing goods) and dutiable goods. It could be a good meta discussion.

Comment: This discussion about tags should be happening on meta, not here.

Answer (score 3):

This has all the hallmarks of some jobsworth throwing his weight around. The existence of such a “regulation” is **very** unlikely if only because “through one of the four major airports” excludes the land crossing at Attari (Wagah). [This form](http://www.immihelp.com/nri/indiavisa/india-visa-pakistan-application-form.pdf) mentions that (though clearly is ancient!) but there are many more recent references to it also.

Silence is hardly conclusive but the details [here](http://www.india.org.pk/eoi.php?id=Visitor%20Visa&q=1) are generally comprehensive and seem very likely to have mentioned such an arbitrary rule, were there one.

The issue may be the initially-chosen (smaller) airport. Not all Indian airports are manned with Immigration officers (for example, at T1, not even New Delhi) and it does make sense to me that Pakistani nationals are required to arrive in India via a point of entry that does have Immigration facilities (which the "select four" do have).

Comment: Could you revise your last para? Something seems wrong with the grammar. I'm not sure what you're trying to say there.

Comment: Actually a lot of airports in India are manned with immigration officers directly from the government. Much smaller airports do have the local police acting the role but a lot of larger and medium-sized airports all over India have officers directly from the immigration bureau. In fact I saw the exhaustive list earlier. I can fetch the link later but you should be able to find it. So I don't think that is the issue. I really do think it's someone giving a hard time and causing unnecessary trouble.

Comment: Yes, it is more specifically a medium-sized airport. It is absolutely on the list. Sorry I can't specify it here.

Comment: It does not really make sense that only Pakistani citizens are required to enter India via airports with immigration facilities. I would rather assume that everyone, even Indian citizens, are only allowed to enter India through designated border control points and that it is extremely unlikely that there are scheduled international flights to any airport in India without immigration facilities.

Comment: Btw about Atari, it wasn't mentioned because it is for land transport and in our case it is air transport, hence not applicable. The four airports were mentioned and Attari skipped because it was clear the intention is to take a flight, not come by land or sea. I notice the form does mention the same list of four ports of entry but is that form still valid and in-use?

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Respectfully, when researching this question, I have found many references in official Indian rules that call out exceptions specifically for Pakistani citizens. I have not yet found the requirement to use those four, and only those four, airports, but there are enough other "these rules apply to everyone, except Pak citizens" rules that it would not surprise me at all.

Comment: @CGCampbell: Due to the tensions in the political relations between India and Pakistan, you are likely correct, but I don't understand what pnuts is trying to say in his last paragraph. Even without any general and "googleable" rules, some countries list allowed points of entry in their issued visa (which may very well be the case here), but if ATDC's friend had a booked international flight to a smaller airport, I don't see why anyone should assume that there is no immigration control there.

Comment: Thank you both for the comments. Just want to clarify that "smaller" does not mean it's very small or rural. It's still a large urban airport with direct international flights from many countries **and** immigration checkpoint facilities. It's just not in the ridiculous list of *"four allowed ports of entry by air travel for Pakistani nationals"*. I'm only trying to find out if this list is still enforced, or is simply a remnant of the past. For privacy and security reasons, I chose not to disclose the exact airport names chosen, but with or without such disclosure this is *no* special case.

Comment: People do cross the wagah border in buses every day. There is a direct bus service between New Delhi and Lahore and these buses cross the border at Attari (wagah border).